# How do I record stopwatch times on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am looking for a way to record times while having a constant timer running, almost like a lap function. I have the stopwatch setup, just need a way to create a lap function. I need it be able to record a lap while still running till it is stopped or another lap is initiated. Can anyone help? Will provide code if needed. Thank you!
*edit added the code of my stopwatch

```
  Widget stopwatch(){
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                stoptimedisplay,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 50.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: stoppressed ? null : stopstopwatch,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 40.0,
                          vertical: 12.0,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Stop",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.white
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: resetpressed ? null : resetstopwatch,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 40.0,
                          vertical: 12.0,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Reset",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.white
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: startpressed ? startstopwatch : null,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 80.0,
                      vertical: 20.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Start",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                          color: Colors.white
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Dart has a [`Stopwatch` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html).  For each lap, you can simply record its current [`elapsed`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Stopwatch/elapsed.html) value.  Example usage:

```dart
void main() async {
  var stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  var lapTimes = <Duration>[];

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    var randomSeconds = random.nextInt(5) + 1;
    print(randomSeconds);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: randomSeconds));
    lapTimes.add(stopwatch.elapsed);
  }

  print(lapTimes);
}
```

Note that the above would record the *cumulative* duration for the laps (i.e., the `Duration`s will be monotonically increasing); if you instead want each individual lap's duration, then you would have to subtract each `Duration` from its previous one:

```dart
  var lapDeltas = [
    lapTimes[0],
    for (var i = 1; i < lapTimes.length; i += 1)
      lapTimes[i] - lapTimes[i - 1],
  ];
  print(lapDeltas);
```

Alternatively you could easily implement `Stopwatch` yourself with `DateTime.now()` by recording a starting timestamp, recording timestamps for each lap, and then computing the differences between the current timestamp and the starting timestamp (or between the current timestamp and the previous timestamp if you want non-cumulative durations).

Answer (score -1):

Please post your code for details, but as far as I understood, I think you can create another lapCounter variable initialized as 0 at first.

```
int lapCounter = 0;
```

Then, in your timer counter function, where you end the timer

```
....myTimer ends here before restarting the counter.
setState(()=> lapCounter += 1);
```

And then function where you reset the progress to zero.

```
setState(()=> lapCounter = 0);
```